# Get Users who are not have relation with another user morphToMany laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel

I have user table and have 4 roles (student, teacher, super admin, parent).
I am linking parent with the student using Morphtomany relation in laravel using this code

```
  public function Parent()
    {
        return $this->morphToMany('App\Models\User', 'user_parent');
    }
```

when a super admin wants to create a new user and choose a role as parent, then the list of students will appear in order to choose the child name from users who have student role.
I want to select only students who are not linked to the parent (the student who still has no relationship with the parent ).
I am using this code to get students from the database

```
   $users = User::whereDoesntHave('Parent')->whereHas(
            'roles', function($q){
            $q->where('id', 5);
        }
        )->get();
```

but this code also returns the students who have a parent. which I don't want to retrieve.

this is the table's schema

```
CREATE TABLE `user_parents` (
  `id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_parent_id` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `user_parent_type` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `user_id` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3157 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `User::doesntHave('parent')` instead of `User::whereDoesntHave('parent')`

As the documentation says (laravel 8): https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-absence

`whereDoesntHave` allows you to specify a where condition. Since you don't specify any, I think that's the reason you still get students with parents.

Comment: thank you for your reply , actually I tried with it and same result  it return all students ,even  those who has parent

Comment: Why do you use a morph relationship? Couldn't you use a hasMany ?

Comment: that what i worked on and i don't want to change it

Comment: Can you update your question with your tables columns please ?

Comment: thanks for reply , I just updated the question with the table schema please check

Comment: Can I see the user table also?

Comment: user table is the laravel's default table